# Waterline/Sails.js mass insertion and deletion with MariaDB

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sails.js, mariadb, waterline

In my Sails.js app, I have a table `auctions`, which contains the data received as of the last dump from the [Battle.net API](https://dev.battle.net/io-docs).

Thus, every time a new dump for a `realm` arrives, I need to clear all rows who are associated with this `realm`, and then insert the newer ones.

I can either do it:

- all-at-once (sending a single query with `destroy()`, and another one with the dump itself);
- or by small batches (grouping them by `item`, then `destroy()`ing all records with `realm` and `item, then inserting the new ones).

I am currently doing it with `async.forEachOfSeries`, with the small batches as described above, but with the current load (45k records inserted each time I run the job) it's unbearably slow, and that does not take into account if I need to update the `item` tooltip records.
If I tried to inserting them all at once, either Node.js starts paging and hangs, or MariaDB takes longer than Waterline allows.

How can I approach this more scalably? Would `async.queue` or `async.cargo` work?

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing all the rows in one table?  Do it this way:

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
2. Load `new` with the new data
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;`
4. `DROP TABLE old;`

It achieves the swap with zero downtime.  You don't need to worry about the efficiency of the LOAD (step 2).

(I leave as an exercise to the reader to translate this MySQL/MariaDB code into sails.js or whatever.)

Comment: Not exacylu, I'm replacing either * all the rows with a given `realm` OR * all the items with a given `realm` and `itemId`. I'll edit the original question for sake of clarification.

Comment: OK not all at once.  Try `REPLACE` or `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.  Those are likely to be faster, but won't handle deleting rows that won't be replaced.